# Как реализовать такое Меню на javascript(jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать скролл у меню на мобильной версии? Фото прикладываю. 
Логика такая: когда пункты меню перестают влезать, должен быть реализован скролл
Спасибо. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CSS `nav { overflow-x: auto; } nav ul { list-style: none; display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; align-items: center; padding: 0; } nav ul li { margin: 0 3rem; padding: 1rem; }` - ну и скроллбар стилизовать (хотя не обязательно, на мобилах он и так тоненький).

Comment: Для этого не используют обычно скроллбар, лучше задать контейнеру этих элементов `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` Таким образом, если элементы не будут влезать, они будут переходить на новую строку. А там уже и можно подредактировать, можете посмотреть как используют `display: flex`

Comment: Если у вас есть какие-то вопросы, можете задать, я отвечу

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Мне именно скролл нужен, такое задание дали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, это то что вам нужно.

**Вариант со скроллом.** Скролл появляется при необходимости. Здесь JavaScript (jQuery) не требуется.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav__min,
#nav__max {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav__ul a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav__min">
  <ul class="nav__ul">
    <li><a href="#">Меню 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="nav__max">
  <ul class="nav__ul">
    <li><a href="#">Меню 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 10</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Вариант без скролла.** С возможностью перетаскивания мышкой. На смартфонах не знаю, будет ли работать, нужно проверять.

```js
$('.nav__ul').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    $window = $(window),
    mouseX = e.pageX,
    width = $this.outerWidth()
  elemX = $this.offset().left + width - mouseX;
  e.preventDefault();
  $window.on('mousemove.drag', function(e2) {
    $this.offset({
      left: e2.pageX + elemX - width,
      right: e2.pageX + elemX - width
    });
  }).one('mouseup', function() {
    $window.off('mousemove.drag');
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.nav__ul a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.nav__ul li {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.nav__ul li:first-child {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.nav__ul li:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.nav__ul {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav__ul">
    <li><a href="#">Меню 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 15</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 16</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 17</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 18</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 19</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 20</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 21</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 22</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 23</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 24</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 25</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 26</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 27</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 28</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 29</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Меню 30</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал не то, что вы хотели, но я сделал более удобное решение для пользователя. Я сделал меню, при клике на которое появляются пунты меню

P.S. чтобы увидеть меню, сожмите браузер до 500px

```js
let burger__menu = document.querySelector('.burger__menu');
let header__nav = document.querySelector('.header__nav');

burger__menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
 burger__menu.classList.toggle('active');
 header__nav.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: white;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #D81829;
 min-height: 100px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.header__ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.header__li {
 margin-left: 5vw;
}

.header__li a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.header__li a::before {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 width: 0%;
 height: 1px;
 background-color: white;
 transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
}

.header__li a:hover::before {
 width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .header__ul {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #D81829;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
 }

 .header__nav {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
 }

 .header__li {
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 .header__nav.active .header__ul {
  transition: .4s opacity ease-in-out,
     .4s visibility ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 }

 .burger__menu {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px 23px;
  max-width: 46px;
  max-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
 }

 .line__burger {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
 }

 .line__burger:first-child {
  transform: translateY(13px);
 }

 .line__burger:last-child {
  transform: translateY(-13px);
 }

 .burger__menu.active .line__burger:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 }

 .burger__menu.active .line__burger:nth-child(2),
 .burger__menu.active .line__burger:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }

}
```

```html
<header class="header">
 <nav class="header__nav">
  <div class="burger__menu">
   <div class="line__burger"></div>
   <div class="line__burger"></div>
   <div class="line__burger"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="header__ul">
   <li class="header__li"><a>О компании</a></li>
   <li class="header__li"><a>Доставка</a></li>
   <li class="header__li"><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
   <li class="header__li"><a>Новости</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```